# Concat multiple files and prepend filename to every line in bash

Tags: bash, csv, concatenation

There are multiple files:

```
1.csv
2.csv
...
```

With some generic content like:

```
[1.csv]
a
b
c

[2.csv]
d
e
f
```

I want to concatenate the content of the files into one file, but with the filename on every line. So the result should look something like:

```
[concatenated.csv]
1.csv;a
1.csv;b
1.csv;c
2.csv;d
2.csv;e
2.csv;f
```

Comment: How many lines in that files?

Comment: Every file might have a different line count

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=';' '{print FILENAME, $0}' *.csv

1.csv;a
1.csv;b
1.csv;c
2.csv;d
2.csv;e
2.csv;f
```

Comment: Can I make that generic to match any csv file?

Comment: This is generic enough. `$0` prints full line.